# Psychological theory behind Daniel M. Oppenheimer's experiment

Tags: cognitive-psychology

I am currently new to Psychology and I have read an interesting article by [Oppenheimer, D. M. (2006)](https://doi.org/10.1002/acp.1178) and understood that having less complex writings have more positive impacts on the author's assessment.

I'm curious whether there is a specific psychology term/concept for this? And, are there any similar experiments conducted by other researchers so far?

#### References

Oppenheimer, D. M. (2006). [Consequences of erudite vernacular utilized irrespective of necessity: Problems with using long words needlessly.](https://doi.org/10.1002/acp.1178) Applied Cognitive Psychology: The Official Journal of the Society for Applied Research in Memory and Cognition, 20(2), 139-156.